# Why is a network is converging slower with Nesterov than with plain SGD?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, gradient-descent

With Nesterov, I had to lower the learning rate to 1e-5 to avoid exploding gradients even though I have He weight initialization. As a result the network is not converging to the same result as the network had with plain SGD. Does it mean that SGD is performing better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesterov momentum works better than SGD in a mathematical idealization of the problem. It requires the following assumptions:

- The cost function is a quadratic bowl in the region you are evaluating
- You are using the correct momentum coefficient

The first assumption could be inaccurate if your cost surface has many local minima in the region you are evaluating. In Geoffrey Hinton's coursera lectures he suggests that using SGD to begin with and adding momentum later in the training may be a better idea because later on in training you will be closer to the global minima and there will be fewer local minima in the region.

The second assumption means that you have a hyperparameter to optimize and you are not guaranteed better results just by using a standard momentum coefficient.

Comment: I trained the network for 20 epochs using plain sgd and then another 20 epochs using Nestrov and the result was much better. It is strange for me how network converged in two different implementation. I did Apply He weight initialization to avoid exploding gradient but it seems didn't help so I'm back to the initial initialization sqr(6/(in+out)) using uniform